VScode extensions - how can I make a context menu item appear on a folder only if it contains files with a specific extension?
In my case let's say I have a specific extension .new and I want a context menu item to appear only in folders containsing files with that extension, how can I do it?
/folderA
  /folderB   <--- context menu should appear here
    /cool.new  

I've tried with regex but VScode is not happy
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "command": "extensionName/my-command",
          "when": "resourceFilename =~ /.+\/.+\\.new$/"
        }
      ]


Could you share a repository or something we can use to test?

you have to set an attribute to the folderB tree item, determine this attribute dynamic by having a file watcher, use that attribute in the when clause

@rioV8 what do you mean by attribute? Would you mind writing an example?

TreeItem.contextValue
